# Wrong difference between dates

Tags: swift, date

I am trying to find out difference between 2 dates in days. Its returning invalid value for days. Even its returning wrong difference in seconds which is leading towards invalid values of days.

```
(lldb) po earliest
▿ 2038-01-16 22:42:52 +0000
  - timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate : 1168987372.695472

(lldb) po self
▿ 2038-02-16 22:42:52 +0000
  - timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate : 1171665772.695472

(lldb) po Calendar.current.dateComponents([.second], from: earliest, to: self)
▿ second: 2678399 isLeapMonth: false 
  - second : 2678399
  - isLeapMonth : false
```

Difference in seconds should be `2678400`, I have checked this on some online date difference websites. Not sure why this weird issue is happening.

Comment: Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day], from: earliest, to: date).day shows 30 and that is correct. What value do you expect?

Comment: You need to print timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate to more decimal places to why you get the result you do.

Answer (score 1):

Convert string date to Date format and the use `timeIntervalSince` to calculate difference between them :

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"

let timeAtPress = dateFormatter.date(from: "2038-01-16 22:42:52 +0000")

let timeAtPress2 = dateFormatter.date(from: "2038-02-16 22:42:52 +0000")

let elapsed = timeAtPress2?.timeIntervalSince(timeAtPress!)
print(elapsed!) //2678400.0
```

For me `Calendar.current.dateComponents` also giving same result :

```
let elapsed2 = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.second], from: timeAtPress!, to: timeAtPress2!)
print(elapsed2) //second: 2678400 isLeapMonth: false
```